# Android ConstraintLayout background color inside RecyceView

Tags: android

I have following layout structure:

```
--CoordinatorLayout
----FrameLayout
------RecyclerView
--------ConstraintLayout
```

I am trying set ConstraintLayout background color. The color is being shown in the design mode alright, but when rendering after compilation the color is not being show.

This is how I create RecycleView in fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedState) {
    Context context = parent.getContext();
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context, VERTICAL, false);
    DividerItemDecoration dividerItem = new DividerItemDecoration(context, VERTICAL);

    RecyclerView recyclerView = new RecyclerView(getContext());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mListAdapter = new ListAdapter(this));
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItem);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    return recyclerView;
}
```

And this is how item is created in adapter.

```
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    final int layout = R.layout.fragment_home_activity_list_empty;
    ViewDataBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, layout, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(binding);
}

//inside R.layout.fragment_home_activity_list_empty

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout ...>
    <data>...</data>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraint"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPureWhite"
        android:padding="@dimen/standard_padding">
        <!-- Content -->
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

What can be wrong here?

Comment: updated the answer please check...please do feel free to update if it works !! :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all avoid displaying error views inside a RecyclerView. Consider separating the RecyclerView and the error view.
The second thing is that adding "match parent" to height of a View inside RecyclerView is a known bug because you won't be able to scroll the RecyclerView. Change "match_parent" to any other dimension and see if it will help.

Comment: Point taken, however changing height to predefined value still doesn't make background color to be rendered.

Comment: Maybe if you will post full layout code I will be able to help you. Please do so.

Answer (score 0):

This because of your  (default `dividerItem` sets a `default solid color` instead of your `colorPureWhite`)

```
 recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItem); // this set a default solid color of the default rectangle, removing this will give proper color
```

To get proper color as you expect you can try this :-

```
DividerItemDecoration dividerItem = new DividerItemDecoration(YourActivity.this,DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL);
dividerItem.setDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable((YourActivity.this,R.drawable.divider));
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItem);
```

Your drawable (divider.xml) :-

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="@color/colorPureWhite"/> 
<size android:height="0.5dp"/>
</shape>
```

> Add a custom drawable to your `DividerItemDecoration` which will have your defined `colorPureWhite` and then it as `addItemDecorator` to your reyclerView.

Comment: Sadly this solution doesn't work either, I tried creating divider drawable as suggested, as well as removing divider completely